# Need to create a datepicker in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I need to create a datepicker in asp.net. 
Got a few in the web but lokking for some thing different.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree Jquery is nice

http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-datepickers-plugins

This is also nice, I have used this many time, very simple:

http://www.graymattersoft.com/NETProducts/GMDatePicker/tabid/68/Default.aspx

Comment: I can vouch for the GMDatePicker control. I've used it on many projects and it's a pleasure to work with, both server- and client-side.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the jQueryUI datepicker plugin:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Here is an example from jQuery UI website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    </script>

<div class="demo">
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
</div><!-- End demo -->
<div style="display: none;" class="demo-description">
<p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.  Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay.  Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ASP.NET Ajax Calendar control?  http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Comment: I use this a lot. It is trivially easy to use.